# How can I create multiple price-sets within one price-set?

Tags: contribution-page, price-sets

I need to create a contribution page with a price set like this..

**TITLE 1**

1. Price-£100
2. Price-£200
3. Other amount

**TITLE 2**

1. Price-£400
2. Price-£600
3. Other amount

We have a events coming up where different category of donation is been assigned and they are referred as "Title 1", 2 etc. within those titles there are separate donation items. Now a contributor should be able to chose a title and select a donation amount within that title. From the admin side of it, we should be able to reciprocate with them or give them gift based on the title & amount they chose.

Comment: Could you given an example of what you are trying to achieve? Concrete examples of "Title1" and "Title 2" would be a start. What should your users be able to do?

Comment: Hi. So the 100 and 200 for each of Title1, Title2 etc can be a single PriceSet radio field - correct? The problem is having the 'other' amount field?

Comment: @petednz yes, you are right, I am able to create the 100, 200 but not the other amount in each titles. Any idea?

Comment: not really. the 'other' would need to be a second field using 'integer'. but what stops you making the Title 2 fields as part of the same Price Set and simply using 'pre field help' to get your Title 2 'title' showing as you need